# Why does drawing using CoreText require increasing the size of the CGRect?

Tags: swift, nsattributedstring, core-text, cgrect

I'm trying to draw text using `CoreText`. I have the following code:

```
guard let context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext() else { return }

let attrString = NSAttributedString(string: "Str")
let path = CGMutablePath()

// Commented code does work, why?
// path.addRect(CGRect(x: 0, y: 50, width: attrString.size().width + 1, height: attrString.size().height + 1))
path.addRect(CGRect(x: 0, y: 50, width: attrString.size().width, height: attrString.size().height))

let framesetter = CTFramesetterCreateWithAttributedString(attrString as CFAttributedString)
let frame = CTFramesetterCreateFrame(framesetter, CFRangeMake(0, attrString.length), path, nil)

CTFrameDraw(frame, context)
```

Why does increasing the size of `CGRect` help, while the actual size of `NSAttributedString` doesn't?

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Try add a font attribute to the attributed string so it is drawn with a known font of a known size.

Comment: Also, from the reference documentation for  `NSAttributedString size`: "*This method may return fractional sizes. When setting the size of your view, use the ceil function to round fractional values up to the nearest whole number."*. So try using `CRect integral` on the rect you create.

Comment: @rmaddy thanks for pointing me, I was using wrong font name in my tests - "Helvetica" whereas it should be "HelveticaNeue". That does solve the issue. You might want to answer question in the post, so I can upvote your help. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When working with an attributed string and getting its size, you need to at least specify a font. The size of `"Str"` will be quite different with an 8 point font versus a 72 point font, for example.

It might also help to convert the calculated `CGRect` into an integral rect which will round up any fractional sizes. Use the `integral` property of `CGRect`.